# Chrome: Get detailed information on GPU activity

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I'm studying a WebGL scene with Chrome's performance tab, and am trying to get more information on what might be causing the GPU to totally block all other activity on the page for multiple seconds upon the first render call:

[image]

I haven't found a way to get deeper insight into GPU activity from the Chrome profile tools though.

Is there a way to see lower-level operations the GPU is performing in a way that's analogous to the way we can investigate execution chains on the CPU? Any help others can offer on this question would be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it will be useful but there is `about:tracing`